# List of things that make one 'as if one rejects the core'

Tags: talmud-gemara, sin, heresy, ikarim

I was recently looking up something about lashon harah, and on Erchin 15A, Rav Yosi ben Zimra says that anyone that says lashon harah it is as if they reject everything, and I know I have seen similar things in the Gemara before (references escape me).

**Is there a list of things about which the Gemara says one is "kofer b'kol"?**

The motivating example for this was lashon harah, where someone was saying it's "not so bad" (i.e. some people seem to treat it with far more importance than other mitzvot that are "more clearly deorita" (not talking about "lo telech rachil" here)), and the Gemara seems to claim it's as bad as killing people. This list would show either (if long) that it's [mostly hyperbolic](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45501/hyperbole-in-the-gemara), and it's just a way of saying that it's bad, or (if very short) that it is in a rather small group of very important mitzvot that really are equivalent to murder.

Comment: Thanks! Next suggestion, add in information about why you want to have such a list.

Comment: @IsaacMoses added, not sure if it made it more muddled though

Comment: soandos, I think it's a singificant improvement. I'm going to go ahead and bold the core question to forestall even a small suspicion of muddle.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, thanks, and will do for next time.