# Hyperbole in the Gemara?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, talmud-gemara

There are [many times](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45499/list-of-things-that-make-one-as-if-one-rejects-the-core) where the Gemara says that someone who does something is equivalent to one who is "kofer b'kol" or killing someone (for example regarding lashon harah in Erchin 15b

I have always been under the assumption that such language is hyperbolic.

Is that the case, or should such things be taken literally?

Comment: Related: "*Keneged Kulam*," analyzed by R' Slifkin in these two posts: http://www.rationalistjudaism.com/2013/09/kneged-kulam.html http://www.rationalistjudaism.com/2013/10/keneged-kulam-redux.html

Comment: Read "The Culture of the Babylonian Talmud" it has a great section about violence in Bavli Gemara.

Comment: I think you will find this amusing, but helpful to your question- https://din.org.il/2022/01/13/%d7%a1%d7%92%d7%95%d7%9c%d7%aa-%d7%a1%d7%a2%d7%95%d7%93%d7%aa-%d7%a4%d7%93%d7%99%d7%95%d7%9f-%d7%94%d7%91%d7%9f/#:~:text=%D7%99%D7%A9%20%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%95%20%D7%91%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%9A%20%D7%97%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%93%2C%20%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%94%20%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%95%20%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A9%20%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%AA%D7%A3,%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9C%20%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94%20%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D7%9E%D7%A9%20%D7%96%D7%94%20%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%A4%D7%A8%E2%

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is pretty explicit in Rambam Laws of Teshuva Ch. 3:

> ‏ [יד] כל אחד ואחד מארבעה ועשרים אנשים אלו שמנינו--אף על פי שהן ישראל, אין להן חלק לעולם הבא.  ויש עבירות קלות מאלו, ואף על פי כן אמרו חכמים שהרגיל בהן אין לו חלק לעולם הבא, כדי להתרחק מהן ולהיזהר מהן.‏
>
> כה  ואלו הן:  המכנה את חברו, והקורא לחברו בכינוי, והמלבין פני חברו ברבים, והמתכבד בקלון חברו, והמבזה תלמידי חכמים, והמבזה רבותיו, והמבזה את המועדות, והמחלל את הקודשים.‏
>
> The above 24 matters [e.g. denying the existence of God] would preclude even a Jew from a share in the World to Come. Some sins are less bad than these [and therefore wouldn't], however the  rabbis said "one who does these regularly will lose his share in the World to Come" in order to make a point and distance a person from them. They are: dubbing a friend with derogatory nicknames or using such nicknames, deeply shaming someone in public, putting oneself on a pedestal by taking advantage of someone else's shame, disgracing scholars or one's own teachers, disgracing the holidays or holy matters.

Similarly, there's a responsum from Rabbi Moshe Feinstein -- OC4:116 -- for someone overcome with sexual guilt. He says when the Zohar, and subsequently the Shulchan Aruch, say a certain sin is "as bad as all others combined", it's "lav davka" -- it doesn't really mean that.

Comment: Is this your translation?

Comment: The point of your Rambam citation seems to be your addition in the brackets.  See Rambam's introduction to Chelek, right before the Ikkarim, which implies that your bracketed addition is inaccurate.

Comment: @soandos The Rambam says יש עבירות קלות מאלו, which sounds pretty clear that they are not in the 24.

Comment: @YEZ confused the sections, and the list, my bad

Answer (score 5):

Tosefos seems to take at least one of them literally.

Tosefos Sotah 10b s.v. נח לו:

> נראה האי דלא חשיב ליה (פסחים דף כה.) בהדי ג' עבירות שאין עומדים בפני פקוח נפש עבודת כוכבים וגילוי עריות ושפיכות דמים משום דעבירת הלבנת פנים אינה מפורשת בתורה ולא נקט אלא עבירות המפורשות
>
> It seems that that which embarrassing someone is not counted among the 3 sins for which one must give up their life is because it is not explicit in the Torah.

Tosefos is bothered that embarrasing someone should be on the halachic list of things for which you give up your life, because the Gemara says that you should throw yourself into a fire rather than embarrass someone.  Tosefos answer is not that it is hyperbolic, but that it was disqualified by a technicality.

Comment: and the Ramban in Milchamos, and Rabbeinu Yonah in Shaarei Teshuva, who all discuss this questoin

Comment: @Matt if you can provide me with citations, I'd like to add them to my answer.

Comment: Shaarei Teshuvah 3:139. The ramban I believe is right there in Sotah along with Tosfos (as is the Meiri who argues on Tosfos and says that the Gemara shouldn't be taken seriously)

Answer (score 3):

This is addressed in a responsum by [R. Isaac Ben Sheshet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_ben_Sheshet) (Shu"t HaRivash # 171). He states that the Sages frequently exaggerated the severity of sins in order to keep the populace from committing them.

> ומה שאמרת שהגאונים והרשב"א ז"ל כתבו שהעובר על החרמים והשבועות הוא בכלל
>   לא ינקה והיינו כעובד ע"ג דכתיב בה ולא ידבק בידך מאומה מן החרם ע"כ אם
>   הפליגו להגדיל העון ההוא כמו שעשו חז"ל שאמרו שבכל עברות שבתורה נאמר בהן
>   ונקה וכאן לא ינקה וכן שנפרעין ממנו ומכל העולם לא אמרו בו שיהרג ואל
>   יעבור כמו באותן ג' עברות וזה לא עלה על דעת שום אדם ולא חשב אנוש אלא
>   שדרך החכמים להפליג בהגדלת העונות כדי שישמר אדם מהכשל בהן אמרו בפ' יש
>   בערכין כל המספר לשון הרע מגדיל עונות כנגד שלש עברות ע"ג וגלוי עריות
>   ושפיכות דמים וכו' וכן במס' נדרים יצא ר' עקיבא ודרש כל שאינו מבקר את
>   החולה כאלו שופך דמים ובפ' ר"א דאורג אמרו הקורע בגדיו בחמתו וכו' יהיה
>   בעיניך כעובד ע"ג היאמר אדם באלו וכיוצא בהם יהרג ואל יעבור הא ליכא
>   למימר

[R. Ezekiel Feivel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yechezkel_Feivel) similarly states (Toldos Adam Chapter 13) that the Sages frequently exaggerated in these types of matters.

> וכמו כן כשרצו חז"ל להרחיק בכל כח את האדם מן העברה הפליגו בזכרון נזקיה
>   עד למעלה דרך משל על עם הארץ אמרו מותר לנחרו ביום כפורים שחל להיות בשבת
>   ולקרעו כדג ומגבו [ועיין בר"ן] אשר דבריהם אלה ואלף כיוצא בהם אין לחשוד
>   כל מי שיש לו לב שיקחם כפשוטם חלילה אבל כך היא דרכן של חכמים להפליג
>   במליצותיהם במקומות רבים ולערב בדבריהם במליצות קשות ומפליאים עד שירגיזו
>   לב הקורא והיא באמת חכמה נפלאה להעיר לב הקורא או השומע להתבונן מה ראו
>   חכמים להעלות המשל הקשה על זה על שפתותיהם ומה הגיע אליהם שיאמרו כזאת
>   וכשיתבוננו היטב יבין האמת יותר מאם היו מבארים לו הדבר באורך ורוחב כי
>   אולי לא היה נותן לב לדבריהם ועכשיו הוא נותן לב ויעשה האמת את שלו

He goes on to quote R. Isaac Ben Sheshet (cited above), and claims that Rambam was alluding to this idea in his Commentary to Sanhedrin 7:4 where he wrote:

> וכבר הזהירו חכמים מאד על ההרהור והרחיקו מגורמיו והאריכו לירא ולהפחיד
>   מקשה עצמו לדעת ומוציא שכבת זרע לבטלה